# i install conda installed and Python installed seperately

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

i have Conda installed and Python installed separately, when i run .py file it is referencing to python's packages not from Conda so some pkg are missing(pandas), Conda has pandas but not Python. all default installations are go to Conda pkg files. how do i install pandas to Python that is not in Conda?

Answer (score 0):

To run a file from conda, simply go to your anaconda prompt and cd into the drive. Similarly, you can search for your python prompt from the start bar and run code from there.

To install pandas into your python installation type:

```
pip install pandas
```

If you are running code from an IDE or code editor, you need to go into your settings and change the default runtime environment to anaconda. Even easier, open your anaconda navigator and then run your editor from there.

Your conda installation can't not have python, although it might be running the wrong version of python for your code. To change the version of python type:

```
conda install python=$pythonversion$
```

into your conda prompt.